# best practice tuple, dynamic or model

Tags: c#, tuples

When are good places to use a `Tuple` instead of some kind of model class? Isn't it just lazy to use `Tuples`?

I'm using `Tuples` or sometimes `dynamics` in various places in my projects and I'm asking myself if creating a model class for each would be a good practice.

**Events**

I'm using Tuples as a payload for some events I write in my PRISM applications because the class `PubSubEvent` only takes one generic type argument.

*Solution:*

- Create a model class and use it instead

*is it a good practice to do so?*

**JSON argument parsing**

When I have a web API access point where I expect a json string as argument, I sometimes cast the string to a dynamic type and read properties out of it and pass it to my managers.

*Solution:*

- Edit the json in the web client and just send the needed data
- Create a argument parser (or however they are called again) and except a model as argument

*is it a good practice to do so?*

**Temporary data storage in algorithms**

In some algorithms I use `Tuples` to store my data temporary. I think in this context `Tuples` are a good thing.

**More?**

Are there more places `Tuples` are useful? When should they be used and when not?

**MSDN**

> Tuples are commonly used in four ways:
>
> 1. To represent a single set of data. For example, a tuple can
>      represent a database record, and its components can represent
>      individual fields of the record.

When working with an database framework I think this is not a good practice?

> 2. To provide easy access to, and manipulation of, a data set.

Ok in algorithms where the code sometimes is hard to read anyway.

> 3. To return multiple values from a method without using out parameters
>      (in C#) or `ByRef` parameters (in Visual Basic).

Isn't this just lazy and hard to read?

> 4. To pass multiple values to a method through a single parameter. For
>      example, the `Thread.Start(Object)` method has a single parameter that
>      lets you supply one value to the method that the thread executes at
>      startup time. If you supply a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` object as the method
>      argument, you can supply the thread’s startup routine with three
>      items of data.

Again Lazy? Can be done with any other model class too?

In my opinion with this knowledge I would say `Tuples` are bad practice. Can somebody show me an good way to use them?

Comment: It is an opinion-based question. I personally use `Tuple`s very rarely...

Comment: I think so. But there are good options and bad ones :)

Comment: has so a place to discuss such things? chat?

Comment: Stackexchange.com perhaps.

Comment: As of now I would agree with you that Tuples do more bad then good. But the new C# 7 will make a better case for [them](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/20/new-features-in-c-sharp-7/)

Comment: @Filip Cordas, how? Or why?

Comment: From what I saw in the https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347#issuecomment-247503388 they want them mostly for a different way of doing out in async methods.

Comment: What I hope will be possible to do is something like (var result1,var result2) = await Task.WhenAll(Method1Async(),Method2Async()); I heard them mention that it will related to params keyword so that will be nice and will save you lot of coding.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Looks like there are really some good things you can do with tuples in c# 7